# Can't get php to display access.txt file in html

Tags: php, html, file, text, echo

This may be a noob question. In which case, sorry. I can't get this php script to read the contents of a txt file in the same directory. It outputs

```
';?>
```

and

```
.$theData.
```

here is the code

```
<article> 
<?php
$Color = "red";
$myFile = "access.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
$theData = fread($fh, 5);
fclose($fh);
echo '<div style="Color:'.$Color.'">'.$theData.'</div>';
?>
</article>
```

Comment: try this echo '<div style="color:'.$Color.'">';echo $theData;echo '</div>';

Comment: You're only reading 5 bytes from it. And you might want to escape HTML entities depending on its content.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
<article> 
<?php
$Color = "red";
$myFile = "access.txt";
$theData = file_get_contents($myFile);
echo "<div style='color:".$Color."'>".$theData."</div>";
?>
</article>
```

Comment: Alas. Same output. Thanks though.